# Hacking an IKEA Bathroom Sink/Cabinet (ENHET / TVÄLLEN) - Possible?

Tags: bathroom, sink, mounting, ikea

Is there any way to "hack" [this ENHET / TVÄLLEN combination](https://www.ikea.com/no/no/p/enhet-tvaellen-servantskap-med-2-skuffer-gra-ramme-gra-pilkan-blandebatteri-s39480094/) so that you could have a long benchtop sitting on the cabinet (extending for a meter to the right), and then cut out a hole in the benchtop so that the pictured sink could then be placed on top? Or would it be impossible to fit a sink meant to fit directly atop a cabinet into a benchtop?

If I haven't been clear enough/if you need more information, just let me know.  Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sure there's a way, but we don't know your skills, so we don't know if there's a way for _you_ to do it. It might require making some brackets for mounting, it might involve wood or metal work, hard to say. Also, it would be nice to link to a picture so people don't have to click links to sites they may not want to visit. Additionally, a drawing describing what you're talking about is worth roughly 1000 words...

Comment: your question boils down to `can I install a spacer between the cabinet and sink?` ... the sink is not designed to fit on only some specific base

Comment: Thanks to both people who responded.  Although I perhaps haven't given enough info for a detailed answer, your responses are actually more than sufficient - because they both confirm that it's almost certainly possible, and that's what I needed to know.  [Regarding my linking to outside sites/not including images/etc. - I just joined Stack Exchange, and this is my first post - in this community or any other - so I admit I don't know all the rules/preferences/etc.  Apologies for any mistakes made.]  Thanks again.